# Heroku HTML static site does not allow json access?

Tags: heroku, rack

I'm using `Rack::TryStatic` to manage my [site](http://mon-site.herokuapp.com/) on Heroku.

This is my config.ru file on [github](https://github.com/alain-andre/mon_site/blob/master/config.ru)

```
require "rack/contrib/try_static"
require "rack/contrib/not_found"

use Rack::TryStatic, {
  root: "_site",
  urls: %w[/],
  try:  %w[
    .html index.html /index.html
    .js .css .xml .json
    .eot .svg .ttf .woff .woff2
  ]
}

run lambda{ |env|
  four_oh_four_page = File.expand_path("../_site/404/index.html", __FILE__)
  [ 404, { 'Content-Type'  => 'text/html'}, [ File.read(four_oh_four_page) ]]
}
```

I think I have allowed `.json` access by adding it in the *try array*, but my `search.json` file get a **404** html page so my searching tool is broken.

Any idea of what I could do to access it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `TryStatic`, the json file is generated during the heroku build but is not present in the final build.